# Yii2 Upgrade version step by step

Tags: yii2, composer-php, upgrade

Im trying upgrade from version Yii 2.0.13 to the last version (2.0.23), but step by step, now need upgrade to 2.0.14 and next to 2.0.15 etc..
I follow the instructions in [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.23/framework/UPGRADE.md) and use this command, but the app upgrade automatically to the last version 2.0.23

```
composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.14" --update-with-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have "~" before "2.0.14" which tells composer to use a newer version up to but not including 3.0

do

```
composer require "yiisoft/yii2:2.0.14" --update-with-dependencies
```

instead

source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: yes you are correct! i copied the command exactly from documentation and they don't explain it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to upgrade step by step, you can upgrade Yii directly from 2.0.13 to 2.0.23. You need to follow all upgrade instructions for all versions between 2.0.13 and 2.0.23, but no need to install all versions between - you can install 2.0.23 directly and make all necessary upgrade changes in one step. This usually gives you less work and possible problems.

Comment: yes, but in upgrade step by step the objective is see what break my app between versions, (i thinks is there are many versions from my to up to 2.0.23) but you are right i can upgrade directly to the last version.

Comment: It may give you just more work, because regression introduced in one version may be fixed in next release. Skipping some versions may save you the trouble of fighting with already fixed bugs.

Comment: seen this way I think I'll follow your suggestion. thanks!