# Upgrade Yii 2 - no composer

Tags: yii2

I have no prior experience with Yii, and their documentation did not provide answers to my questions, so here we are:

I have a Yii2 project (2.0.42), which has been installed without composer. Can I upgrade it to the latest version using composer? If yes, how can I do that?

If that is not possible, how can I upgrade it to the latest version using the archive file that I have downloaded?

Comment: have you tried `composer require "yiisoft/yii2:2.0.xx" --update-with-dependencies` ? taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217794/yii2-upgrade-version-step-by-step

Comment: As I said, Yii2 It has been installed without composer. Can I use composer require, even if the installation has been done from archive and not from composer? If yes - how?

Comment: I've never tried it so I can't say for sure. But, you probably can use composer require. I would check in what folder the current Yii is installed. If it's in vendor folder I would remove it to avoid conflict with composer installation. After installing the yii with composer you will need to change path to yii in `/web/index.php`, `/web/index-test.php` and `/yii` files. You might also need to check config files to see if `@yii` alias is overwritten. You should also check Yii2 upgrading instruction to see if you need to do some modifications to your code.